# Fixing carousel container size in Angular-UI-Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [Angular-UI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for my project. In the carousel, I have to load **images of different dimensions**, some are bigger and some are smaller than the container. How can I fix the size of the carousel container such that the carousel will not resize upon loading a new image everytime, while the loaded image can fit into the container and maintaining its original ratio?

```
<div style="height:305px;">
    <carousel interval="carousel_interval">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
        </slide>
    </carousel>
</div>
```

Currently, I am using the code extracted from the sample from the [Angular-UI-Bootstrap carousel section](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel). It does not work as I am loading in images of various dimensions.

The code is tested on Google Chrome version 38.0.2125.122 m.

Comment: Related: [Twitter Bootstrap carousel different height images cause bouncing arrows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391566/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-different-height-images-cause-bouncing-arrows).

Comment: here's a solution for this in the follow link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38447057/4767208

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <carousel interval="carousel_interval">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="max-height:300px; margin:0 auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
        </slide>
    </carousel>
</div>
```

I used `col-md-6` in the topmost `div` element and applied `style="max-height:300px; margin:0 auto;"` to the `img` element.

Now, images of different sizes can fit into the carousel very well.