# Why I can't use sliding pictures in modal window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one button, when click on him I created to open modal window. In modal window I created carousel slider, i have problem with sliding on chevron left and right, thats not working, on my computer images sliding on 5 seconds, but on jsfiddle sliding not working, can you tell me what is problem with sliding on chevron left and right. 
On my big project I have 2 sliders, and when i click on chevron in modal window  my page scrolling down

JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/802/

HTML

```
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">CLICK HERE</button>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <divclass="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="http://cdn.banquenationale.ca/cdnbnc/2013/06/ruisseau.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                           <img src="http://pixdaus.com/files/items/pics/4/68/127468_81126581de22e05a9a66d3216ae2b4ad_large.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://www.naturehighlights.com/images/25.1_Canada.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#locations" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#locations" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </a>

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the id of the Carousel and you mixed class attribute with div tag.

```
<div id="locations" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

[Updated Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/t9q2mwze/2/)

```
<a class="left carousel-control" data-target="#locations" data-slide="prev">
     &lsaquo;
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" data-target="#locations" data-slide="next">
     &rsaquo;
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: not working in my case, i don't know why, when i click on right my backgroumd page scrolling down, indicator right and left not working, i also change locations to locations3 on all place

Comment: i solved on down hwere is chevron right or left, i replace href with data-target and working

Comment: do you know how to set fixed widht and height, and into that window to show picture fitted to modal display, because now my window moving top and down when sliding picture because widht and height of picture not same

Comment: @RS92 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391566/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-different-height-images-cause-bouncing-arrows

Answer (score 1):

Give id to your carousel and just add following jquery lines:

```
$(function(){
  $('#carousel').carousel();
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/803/)

**Update:** same slider id you have to give on left and right button.

See [**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/806/) Its working with left right button also.

Comment: Slider not working, when I click on circle right or left